# API VK C# требуется имя метод

Tags: c#, .net, vkontakte-api, vknet

ошибка Требуется имя метода

```
int appID = ****;
string nomer = login.Text;
string password = pass.Text;
Settings settings = Settings.All;

var vk = new VkApi();
vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams (), appID, nomer, password, settings());
```

Comment: При использовании api vk нужно следить за именами и типами данных переменных, функций, так чтобы они совпадали с документацией.

Answer (score 1):

```
vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
{
    ApplicationId = appID,
    Login = nomer,
    Password = password,
    Settings = Settings.All
});
```